# Print Crystal Reports object direct to Printer from Windows Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I am writing a VB .net windows service which retrieves data from a SQL database, and then outputs it directly to an assigned printer. The idea is that it will automatically generate customer documentation and print it straight out.

I am currently using (for lack of a flexible enough alternative) Crystal Reports. I have created the report within my project and the current code is as below:

```
    Dim factory As New DatabaseProviderFactory()
    Dim myDb As SqlDatabase
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet
    Dim x As New myReport
    Dim p As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim pg As New System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings


    myDb = factory.Create("mydb")

    ds1 = myDb.ExecuteDataSet("sp_to_get_data")


    x.SetDataSource(dsPickList)
    p.PrinterName = "\\\\printserver\\printername"

    x.PrintToPrinter(p, pg, False)
```

The p and pg variables have been added after a bit of googling around. Prior to this i was using the copies, collated, startpage, endpage version of the function.

Code appears to execute perfectly right up to the point where I call PrintToPrinter, at which point it just exits with code 0. No output is seen at all.

As well as the code above, I have the following in my app.config file:

```
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>  </startup>
```

This appears to be a bug in the version of Crystal Reports (according to other posts I have seen), but I am unable to find a suitable way around it in the code.

Project is currently 32-bit compiled against .NET 4.5.1.
Crystal version is 13.0.18.2192

Any suggestions?